# Scroll animation on the canvas not working

Tags: css

Using the canvas, the image changes when scrolling.
I wrote the code for animation.
If css gives you the same value as positio:absolute top:4000px,
Even if I scroll, the animation doesn't work.
It works if you lower the top value. I have to operate at the top 4000px position.
I'm curious about the solution

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('macbook');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var scrollYPos = 1000;
var img = new Image();

img.src = "img/AirPods Max/large0.jpg";

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    scrollYPos = Math.round (window.scrollY/5);
    
    
    console.log(scrollYPos);

    if (scrollYPos> 52) {
        scrollYPos = 52;
    } 

    player(scrollYPos);
});

function player(num) {
    img.src = `img/AirPods Max/large${num}.jpg`;
}

img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
})
```

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4000px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="img-sequence">
        <canvas width="1004" height="1214" id="macbook"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don’t fully understand but if scrollY is large don’t you always get the same image, 52?

Comment: 52 images to use